# Unable to access struct data using arrow notation when pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have created an array of structs and I am getting a BAD_ACCESS error. When I switch everything to dot notation it works fine, why is this?

**Struct**

```
typedef struct data{
    int num;
}data;
```

**Main**

```
int main(void){
  // This works
  data data[4];
  data[0].num = 10;
  printf("Number is = %d\n", data[0].num);

  // This does not work
  data *data[4];
  data[0]->num = 10;
  printf("Number is = %d\n", data[0]->num);
```

Comment: The _arrow notation_ applies for pointers only.

Comment: You don't create objects with this line `data *data[4];`. This creates an array of pointers. So there are no objects behind the pointer and it can't work.

Comment: Stay away from raw arrays and pointers in c++. There's usually everything you need provided with standard containers or dynamic memory management (smart pointers).

Comment: What would work in C is `data *dptr = &data[0]; dptr->num = 10;`

Comment: `typedef struct data{
    int num;
}data;` - That's a very *C-ish* way to do that. And you may also want to revisit the wisdom of naming types and variables the same. In C++ you'd usually do `struct Data { int num; }; Data data;`.

Comment: Are you writing C code or C++ code? With both tags, it's very hard to provide a high quality answer.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you can get rid of the `typedef`.  You can declare variables as `data data[4];`.  **I highly recommend using different names for types and variables.** In your example, the variable `data` is confused with the struct `data`.

Comment: You should be getting a compiler error when the second `data` array is declared.  Choose a different name.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should be using `std::vector<data>` instead of an array.  Arrays can overflow.  Arrays that are too big are a waste of memory.  You will need to use `new` and `delete` to allocate the memory for the arrays during run-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// This does not work
data *data[4];
data[0]->num = 10;
printf("Number is = %d\n", data[0]->num);
```

Since `data` is an array of four pointers, `data[0]` is the first of those four pointers. But what does it point to? Since you haven't done something like `data[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct data));`, it points to nothing in particular -- uninitialized garbage. It's not surprising that trying to write to what the pointer points to causes a bad access error.

Before you dereference a pointer, you need to make the pointer actually point to something.

Comment: I don't think mentioning `malloc` in an answer to a question tagged C++ is a good idea.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Unfortunately, the question is tagged both C and C++ which results in a poorer answer. I want to keep the answer simple and clear, so don't want to address the differences between the two languages.

Comment: Fair enough I guess.

Comment: It's frustrating. I can't give the perfect C answer. I can't give the perfect C++ answer. I don't want to get in the weeds with complex discussions of the differences between the two languages in response to a simple question and likely confuse the OP who most likely is only writing in one language. So what can I do?

Comment: Given the dual tag you did what you could. Have an upvote.

Comment: Also, I believe there is an issue with `data data[4]` and `data * data[4]` being declared in the same function.  How does the compiler know which `data` to refer to?

Comment: This case is particulary bad as your `data[0] = malloc(sizeof(data));` isn't right either (`sizeof(data)` gives the size of the local name data array, not the size of the data type...)

Comment: C code apologies. How come it works using dot notation without having to malloc?

Comment: @RonanMacF It has nothing to do with the notation, it has to do with what type of variable you create. If you create an array of `data`s, then you have a `data` whose `num` member you can set. If you create an array of pointers, all you have are pointers and no `data`. In the first case, `(&data[0])->num = 10;` would work too and in the second case `(*data[0]).num = 10;` wouldn't work either.